# What are these green and orange dots on the Soviet Installation map?

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

I am playing *Rise of the Tomb Raider* on PC.

When I press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key, I get the map, and I see (red arrow highlighted) green/orange dots and dotted lines.

What do they mean? How can these be useful to me as a player?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks I wasn't just looking properly on the map, my bad.

It is clearly specified what these mean in the top right-hand corner.

This time you go near the dot only if you need.

[image]